# How to get the number of items on page with this pagination code?

Tags: php, mysql, math, pagination

I have built a successful pager in PHP with MySQL that works really well. The question I have is more like a math problem. I will not cumbersome you with all the code to keep it short and clean. I'm only posting the essentials for you to understand.

I'm trying to show the number of results per page :

```
    $row_count = total rows from database
    $items_per_page = whatever number inserted here creates the total number of pages.

    Showing results '.$items_per_page*$page.'/'.$row_count.'
```

The math above does not make any sense. If I have 72 rows from the table and display 50 items per page, this gives me 2 pages. The first page will have 50 items and the second page will have 22 items. The problem is on the second page it will show : `Showing results 100/72`. On the second page, the user should see `Showing results 72/72`.

What is the math/algorithm to make this work? I'm sure it's really silly but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only want to count whole pages, thus:

```
$displayed_items = ($row_count - $items_per_page*($page - 1)) > $items_per_page ? $items_per_page*$page : $row_count;
echo "Display results " . $displayed_items . "/" . $row_count;
```

Effectively:

Calculate how many items remain include what you're displaying (hence $page - 1 ). Pg 1 this would be 72 - 0 = 72. Pg2 this would be 72 - 50 = 22;

If the remaining number is higher than what is displayed on each page, then you simply have the page # * items per page. For pg 1, 72 > 50, so show 50 * 1 = 50.

If the remaining number is lower than what is displayed per page, you are showing the the last of the rows (total number of rows). For pg 2, 22 < 50 so show 72 (the total).

Edit: Because you wouldn't want to use your ternary in-line. You could also split it into an if/else statement

```
if( $row_count - $items_per_page * ($page - 1) > $items_per_page ) {
   echo "Showing results " . $items_per_page * $page . "/" . $row_count;
} else {
   echo "Showing results " . $row_count . "/" . $row_count;
}
```

Comment: Yes. Using a ternary in-line gave me a parse syntax error. Your edit works and it is the correct answer!

Comment: I've added an additional edit for how the ternary could have been used.

Answer (score 0):

It will display correctly until the final page which is short so incorrect.

I'd do an if statement and then reduce accordingly for the final page

If you can share more code I can write the code to do this